# Xcode Automation tool for UI test

Tags: iphone, xcode, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, ui-testing

I am writing a javascript UI Automation testing script.  How can it take screenshots of running tests?

Comment: you have generated a javascript file?

Comment: You use javascript file to perform UIAutomation.

Comment: yes, i have generated a js file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS code, you can take screenshots with the UIATarget methods captureScreenWithName and captureRectWithName:

[captureScreenWithName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/captureScreenWithName)

[captureRectWithName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/captureRectWithName)

For example:

```
target = UIATarget.localTarget();
application = target.frontMostApp();
target.captureScreenWithName("myscreenshot");
```

Then, if you hit the Record button in Instruments to replay your script, when the run finishes and stops, you should find your screenshot in your test results directory.

On my system the screenshot saved after running the above example is located here:

```
~/Instruments/myscreenshot.png
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the path of save screenshot?